# ViewData of newly created item in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a ViewData to pass the title of the newly created item from my controller to a view. What would be the best way to do that? Any help would be appreciated.

The following is an example of my controller Create action:

```
public ActionResult Create(Movie newMovie) {

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.AddToMovies(newMovie);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
else
{
    return View(newMovie);
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Index` action is using `Index.cshtml` View, and the `ViewModel` of that View is a `string`, you can try this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.AddToMovies(newMovie);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View("Index", newMovie.Title);
}
```

Alternatively, if your `ViewModel` is not just the movie title, you can use `ViewData` to achieve the same result:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.AddToMovies(newMovie);
    db.SaveChanges();

    ViewData["MovieTitle"] = newMovie.Title;

    return View("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are redirecting to another Action you need to specify something to pass into it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string title)
{
    //take the title and put it into your ViewBag or view model
    ViewBag.NewTitle = title;
    return View();
}
```

So in your example you would do the following to provide the new title to the Index action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { title = newMovie.title });
```

Then within your view you can do:

```
<h1>@ViewBag.NewTitle was created!</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. What if I'm not trying to redirect to an action and instead just want to return the new item itself?

Comment: In order to return the new item without a redirect, you would need to make the post via javascript using ajax, then handle the returned partial view (or Json) to update your page.  Typically in your scenario you would redirect to a Details action that is setup to take an id so as to do a select against your data source on the movie by ID (or some other primary key).  So when the user hits 'save' or what have you, they are taken to a page that shows the details of the movie that was just created.